# Apply deep_symbolize_keys! to array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`deep_symbolize_keys!` converts string keys to `symbol` keys. This works for hashes and all sub-hashes. However, I have a data like this:

```
arr = [
   {'name': 'pratha', 'email': 'p@g.com', 'sub': { 'id': 1 } },
   {'name': 'john', 'email': 'c@d.com', 'sub': { 'id': 2 } }
]
arr.deep_symbolize_keys! # this is not working for array of hashes.
```

In this case, hashes are in an array. So how can i symbolize all at once?

Using Ruby `2.6.3`

I also read somewhere that this is `deprecated` (*probably on one of the Rails forum*). Is that true? If so, what is the best way to convert keys to symbols in my case?

Currently using this:

```
def process(emails)
  blacklist = ["a", "john", "c"]
  e = emails.map do |hash| 
    blacklist.include?(hash['name']) ? nil : hash.deep_symbolize_keys!
  end

  e
end
```

Comment: "this is not working for array of hashes." - of course not. Iterate the array with `.each` and call the method on its elements (which will be hashes)

Comment: I think that too. Array is quite large. Maybe there is a faster way to apply symbolization rather than loop. That's why I asked for.

Comment: Nope, you can't avoid the loop.

Comment: Got it. I will go with that way.

Comment: Any methos you use will iterate over the elements of the array. Maybe the method just hides that for you. The docs says nothing about it being deprecated https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys-21

Comment: Yes, I look deeper and it was similar name for Rails. No issues on Ruby side. I just did `array.map` to mutate. It just works.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need a copy or an in-place transformation? In-place you can use `arr.each(&:deep_symbolize_keys!)`. For a copy you should use `arr.map(&:deep_symbolize_keys)`. Remember that map does not mutate but returns a new array.

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look at bottom. How can I write this block with `each`? Because it isn't working when switch to each

Comment: Where do you use that result of the map? What should the method do?

Comment: I send data to user (This is a Rails Web App). Result came from database, it contains names and emails then printed to browser. Due to I am using some entities, i need to convert keys to symbols before sending to user.

Comment: You should separate blacklisting from symbolization. First filter out those that are in the blacklist, then symbolize. If this is some defined input there is no reason to spare memory with in-place transformations, so you can use `map`, it is no big deal.

Comment: Man you make my day

Answer (score 2):

The implementation already handles nested arrays, it just doesn't define the method on `Array`. So, nest it in a temporary hash and symbolize that. This works for arbitrary types:

```
[1] pry(main)> def deep_symbolize_keys(object) = {object:}.deep_symbolize_keys[:object];
[2] pry(main)> deep_symbolize_keys([{"a" => 1}, {"b" => {"c" => 2}}])
=> [{:a=>1}, {:b=>{:c=>2}}]
```

Also, be careful with your key syntax. In your example, your keys are *already* symbols - they're just quoted symbols:

```
[3] pry(main)> {a: 1}.keys.first.class
=> Symbol
[4] pry(main)> {'a': 1}.keys.first.class
=> Symbol
[5] pry(main)> {'a' => 1}.keys.first.class
=> String
```

The syntax is necessary to handle cases like `{'a-b': 1}[:'a-b']`, but it's very often misleading since they look so much like string keys. I recommend avoiding it entirely unless absolutely necessary - stick to `{a: 1}` for symbol keys and `{'a' => 1}` for string keys.

Comment: Great simple general solution  What’s the unusual {object:} syntax? Is that a shortcut for {object: object} ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - it's the shorthand hash syntax from Ruby 3.1